# Получение параметра url

Tags: php

Как получить параметр `section` из url следующего вида?

```
localhost/page?section=1
```

Обычный `print_r( $_GET )` возвращает `Array ( [/page] => )`, вовсе без параметра `section`.

Apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: cms или framework? какой и что это и как настроен apache?

Comment: @Naumov Добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте следующую функцию: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Ответ - ссылка.